# How to log all HTTP Headers in Apache http server 2.4.43 for a specific port

Tags: apache, logging, http-headers, httpserver

I have tried modifying the httpd.conf, but none of them yield the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable dumpio logging to log HTTP request and response header.

```
DumpIOInput On
DumpIOOutput On
LogLevel dumpio:trace8
```

You can refer https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dumpio.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer it worked. is there any option to change the log file to a user defined log file instead of error.log??

Comment: what do you mean by user-defined log? Do you want to change log file name?

Comment: required to log to a new log file (say, headerList.log) instead of error.log.

Comment: now. But you can set LogLevel inside VirtualHost so it will only apply for particular VirtualHost.

Answer (score 0):

The solution reported by @Pandurang is almost correct.
the configuration is changed as below:

```
DumpIOInput On
DumpIOOutput On
LogLevel dumpio:trace8
```